# Can't SSH into vagrant CentOS box on Windows 8

Tags: windows, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant, centos6

Vagrant is giving me headaches and stealing my weekend.

I just can't ssh into any CentOS box. I'm using the box provided here http://nrel.github.io/vagrant-boxes/. In the meantime I've also tried a couple of other Centos 6.4 boxes, to no avail. (Shouldn't this just work? *sigh*)

**NB!** I have no problem SSH-ing into the basic Ubuntu box (precise32) mentioned in the Vagrant Getting Started.

I'm trying the most simple Vagrantfile, just providing the box and prolonging the timeout.

After `vagrant up` Vagrant gives me this long ominous message that it wasn't able to boot and that there are many reasons why this might be so.

> Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. This can mean
>   a number of things.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

But the box is running, so I try to SSH into it with Putty, which doesn't work either, I get a timeout as well or the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have no clue what that means and didn't find any info that leads anywhere.

Has anyone got a clue why I'm having these problems? Has anyone had success with a CentOS box on Windows 8?

Comment: This isn't off-topic. Vagrant is a tool used primarily for programming.

Comment: The situation could be because of VirtualBox failed to redirect ports, despite saying 
'**==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)**'
You may have a look at full description in my question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529651/virtualbox-nat-failed-to-redirect-tcp-127-0-0-12222-10-0-2-1522).
I still have no idea how to fix redirection fail(
Please drop a note in my post, if and how you succeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting answer for this question. It turns out, I needed to enable **Virtualization**  in my **BIOS settings** :-O Really? Really!

Certain newer Intel as well as AMD processors can handle 32 bit boxes but not 64 bit. That's why I was able to properly boot precise32 but not my centos 64 box.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to solve it by creating my own i386 version of the CentOS Vagrant box on an OS X machine. I put it up on github: https://github.com/Label305/vagrant-centos/releases/tag/v6.5-alpha. However I still wasn't able to start it on Windows 8. I tried to run with `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` but this wasn't much help either since the verbose messages are very difficult to understand.